# What kind of bounds for $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda(A))$ when $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(A + A^t) < 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

What can be said about the real parts of eigenvalues of $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ when $\lambda_{\max}(A + A^t) < 0$?

I think the real parts of eigenvalues of $A$ will be negative, but I can't prove it mathematically.

Comment: I may have written it ambiguous way. I'm considering what bounds for $\lambda_{max}(A)$ we can get when $\lambda_{max}(A+A^t) < 0$ is satisfied. Or am I just not understanding your answer?

Comment: Let $\lambda>0$ be an eigenvalue of  $A$ with eigenvector $v$.
Then $\langle(A+A^t)v,v\rangle=\langle Av,v\rangle+\langle v,Av\rangle=2\mathrm{Re}(\lambda)\langle v,v\rangle$.
So the self-adjoint $A+A^t$ is not negative-semidefinite, so it has an eigenvalue $>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So is it correct that you have shown me the contrapositive of the $\lambda_{max}(A+A^t)<0 \Rightarrow \mathrm{Re}(\lambda(A)) < 0$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is quite basic and has been answered in a comment.